# How do you decide in which entity classes to put JPA NamedQuery annotations?

Tags: java, jpa, jakarta-ee, named-query

Say I have a Customer - CustomerOrder one-to-many bi-directional relationship with the CustomerOrder holding the total value of each order.

If I had a query to find the total value of all orders for a particular customer :

```
select SUM(o.orderValue) from CustomerOrder o where o.customer = :customer
```

Does it matter in which entity class this is annotated? Why would you put it in one or the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does it matter in which entity class this is annotated?

From a technical point of view, it doesn't matter as you will use the `name` of a `@NamedQuery` to call it.

> Why would you put it in one or the other?

But, from a "logical" point of view, putting the `@NamedQuery` where is "naturally" belongs will definitely ease the maintenance. In your example, I would put the query in the `CustomerOrder` entity because the query **is** about finding `CustomerOrder`, this is just where I'd expect to find it if I had to look for it.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter.
The general principle is to put it where it belongs logically. In your case - it'd better be in `CustomerOrder`

Answer (score 1):

Put them in the XML mapping files which should be declared in the persistence.xml. See this great link: [arjan-tijms.omnifaces.org/2010/09/where-to-put-named-queries-in-jpa](http://arjan-tijms.omnifaces.org/2010/09/where-to-put-named-queries-in-jpa.html)

Lots of queries do not 'naturally' belong with the entity (and further you have to modify the entity code, if you put them there, each time you need a new query).